# Is it possible to automatically apply materials and export model?

Tags: python, materials, scripting

I have around 200 materials that I want to apply to an object, one at a time, and export as glb, so I have one version of the model with every texture. Is it possible write a script that applies one material, exports as a glb file, applies the next material, exports, and so on until all the materials have been applied and exported?

Comment: Yes it is fairly easy to automate with scripting.  you loop on materials.  In the loop set material slot 0 of the object to the current material and call the glb exporter.

Comment: Hello and welcome. As it stands this question is too broad to be answerable without requiring an extensive tutorial or description. You should show efforts towards reaching your goal, describing what you have tried and why it failed, so we don't risk recommending something you already know. The scope should also focus on a particular step you encountered an issue with. Describing the whole procedure from start to finish would be too lengthy to explain, and is beyond the goal of this site. If you could [edit] your post to focus on where you are stuck we can vote to reopen it.

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos This question is much less broad than many similar questions we leave open, an d already has an answer.  I'm voting to reopen.

Comment: I have tried to specify a little, but the answer I got really helped, so I think it should be possible to understand what my problem is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, here is pseudocode for an example script that would do that:

```py
import bpy

object = bpy.context.active_object

materials_to_use = ['reddish', 'bluish']

for material_name in materials_to_use:
    object.material_slots[0].material = bpy.data.materials[material_name]
    bpy.ops.export_scene.gltf()
```

This script makes an assumption that you only have a single object that you want to change the material on and that you only care about the first material.  Adjust accordingly.

The 'pseudo' part comes in figuring out `materials_to_use`.  Above I manually listed material names.  That's fine for a few materials but you have around 200 so you'll need to construct the list some other way.  Or you could simply do it for every material in the blend file and then sort it out by deleting outputs.  In that case

```py
import bpy

object = bpy.context.active_object

for material in bpy.data.materials:
    object.material_slots[0].material = material
    bpy.ops.export_scene.gltf()
```

Oh, and I left out a step:  setting the file name for export_scene to use. `bpy.ops.export_scene.gltf()` takes a `filepath="SOME PATH` argument.  You need to output each material to a different path.  The usual technique is to set a directory name before the loop and create a file name like `material.name + '.glb'` in the loop and using the combined directory + file name as the `filepath` argument.

Here is one way to do that with my original example

```py
import bpy
from pathlib import Path

object = bpy.context.active_object

materials_to_use = ['reddish', 'bluish']

dir = Path("C:/tmp")

for material_name in materials_to_use:
    object.material_slots[0].material = bpy.data.materials[material_name]
    file = material_name + ".glb"
    bpy.ops.export_scene.gltf(filepath=str(dir / file))
```

and for every material

```py
import bpy
from pathlib import Path

object = bpy.context.active_object
dir = Path("C:/tmp")

for material in bpy.data.materials:
    object.material_slots[0].material = material
    file = material.name + ".glb"
    bpy.ops.export_scene.gltf(filepath=str(dir / file))
```

Comment: After some trial and error I got it to work with a few manually listed items, but I didn't understand how to do it with every material in the blend file, like you said I could do. Could you explain a little more?

Comment: it's my second loop.  you want `for material in bpy.data.materials` but instead of `material name` when you create the file string use `material.name`  I've written it out in my answer now.  (Also added the missing right parenthesis)

Comment: When I run that script, it only exports with the first material. Any ideas on what the problem could be? I accepted your answer, but I don't have enough reputation to upvote

Comment: No problem on the upvote. Off the top of my head I don't.  The last script should work for every material in your file -- at least it does in my version.  Are you sure you've got the code exactly right?

Comment: I just figured it out. I had to remove the second `bpy.ops.export_scene.gltf()`. Guess the program got confused when there was nothing in the parenthesis or something. Also had to add an r before the filepath: `dir = Path(r"C:\tmp")`.